# react.js bring component at top/before

Tags: reactjs

Here is my code on [CodeSanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/loginoauth2-tcp8m).

I have a component `FontAwesome` from *FontAwesome* library and button. Now components hierarchy in render method, is like:

```
button
    FontAwesome
```

**Now when it gets rendered I can't see the component `FontAwesome`, how can I bring it on the top, like `css`'s `::before` ?**

If I change the hierarchy it doesn't work.

```
<button onClick={this.startAuth} className={`${provider} ${disabled} button`}>
     <FontAwesome name={provider} />
</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-fontawesome), this library does not include any of the CSS for Font Awesome and expects you to add it to the project yourself.

If you prefer a CDN, you can add it from [here](https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/fontawesome/)

[Updated Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-58682837-673vb) (Note the external resources has a `font-awesome` CSS file)

You can add it to `index.html` with:

```
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
/>
```

Comment: well,I can see it working but, I can see no changes , where have you made it ?

Comment: I couldn't find any change, see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGkPB.png). The only change I see is in `package.json`, it's the project name

Comment: @MaifeeUlAsad just a Codesandbox thing, that's why I specifically mentioned to check external resources. All you need to do is link [css](https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css) in your index.html